# Why a nested class can't have a member the type of which is the one of the enclosing class?

Tags: c++, nested, inner-classes

One of the methods of a class `C` needs to return a `struct` containing a pair of integers and a fresh instance of `C`. It may look awkward, but given the overall design, this makes a lot of sense (think of a `Waveform` class returning a range of itself as a copy, with the indication of where the range starts and ends).

The problem is that this doesn't seem to be allowed. I can redesign my class in order to circumvent this issue but can you explain me **why**, from the point of view of the compiler, this cannot be done

```
struct S {
    struct S2 {
        S s;
    };
};
```

as `S` is an incomplete type (this is the compiler error), and instead this is perfectly fine

```
struct C {
    struct C1 {
        C makeC() { return C(); }
    };
};
```

Where is a substantial difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the point where you attempt to define `S::S2`, the type `S` is still an *incomplete type*, since its definition hasn't been completed yet. And class data members must have a complete type.

You can easily fix it like this:

```
struct S
{
    struct S2;   // declare only, don't define

    // ...
};

struct S::S2
{
    S s;         // now "S" is a complete type
};
```

It is essentially a design decision of C++ to not consider a type complete until the end of its definition. This prevents many pathological situations like the following example:

```
struct X
{
    struct Y { X a; };

    int b[sizeof(Y)];      // "sizeof" requires a complete type
};
```

Comment: I know it can't be done because it can't be done. But why it can't be done?

Comment: @gd1: Because it makes no sense to define something to be something that's not defined...?

Comment: @gd1 I think Kerrek already answered it. How an incomplete type can be defined ?

Comment: I can provide you with a design case in which it makes sense, from a theoretical point of view. But let's say it does not make sense. Then why it makes sense returning something the type of which is not defined? The compiler in this case could just scan S, determine its size and then dig into S2. Why not?

Comment: @gd1: It doesn't. By the time you *call* the function, you must have defined the return type. But that's not related to when you *declare* the function.

Comment: Semantics of member function returning an object is entirely different from an object being member of a class.

Comment: @Mahesh : I know. But there are good reason to to this either. I'll post a simplified version of my design.
@ KerrekSB: Why the compiler cannot just scan S, determine its size, and then dig into S2, as the size of S does not depend on S2?

Comment: @gd1: Because that's how the language is specified. It allows for essentially single-pass parsing, if you will. Ask the language creators, though.

Comment: @gd1: And imagine if the world worked like you fancied. Then you could write, `struct X { struct Y { X a; }; int b[sizeof Y]; };` Shudder.

Comment: @KerrekSB: this last code snippet has, itself, more meaning to me than all the answers you all posted so far. Consider adding it to the answer itself so that I may accept it if no better answers are posted. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to define a class you need a full definition of all the embedded (non-reference and non-pointer) members. While defining a class the class is not fully defined. That is, within a class definition the class under definition is merely declared, not defined.

That said, you can still have a member of your class in a nested class. You just need to define the nested class after the outer class is defined:

```
struct S {
    struct S2;
};

struct S::S2 {
    S s;
};
```

Since `S` is completely defined with the first closing braces, it can be used as embedded member after this point.

When you define a member function inside the class definition the definition is resolved as if it appears immediately after the class definition on the closest namespace level. That is, member function definitions know the fully defined class. The same doesn't apply to nested classes.

Comment: Why is it necessary for S to be complete? The compiler could just scan S, determine its size, and then dig into S2 - as S2 does not affect the size of S. Please explain, I can't imagine the reason!

Comment: @gd1: The basic reason for the definitions being incomplete inside the class definition is that this cleanly gets rid of any potential of recursive inclusion of objects: without the rule it would seem sensible to define a `S2` member for `S`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly why, but I could speculate on this counter-example:

```
struct S {
    struct S2 {
        S s;
    };
    S2 s2;
};
```

An attempt to scan `S` and determine its size before `S2` is scanned will fail in this case. I suspect recursion may impose difficulties on the compiler and such difficulties are often reasons for rules in the standard.

That said, I think your solution is not very appropriate to the problem you have described. I'd make `S2` a template on `S`, and not nested anyway. Then I would be able to use a reference `S&` for the template parameter, rather than `S` itself. So a range would be represented by the two integers and a reference to the original array object. Making a fresh copy from this range would be a separate operation.

Comment: +1 Nice answer. However, in my code the original array object may be altered. There's why I would like to return a copy of it at the time it was not. And the caller doesn't know what portion of the array is going to be altered. I'll end up making a pre- function which only returns the gonna-be-altered range.

Comment: Of course, you should make a copy if the original is going to change. But the range is actually a *view* of the original and it's clearer if it contains a reference--the copy could be explicit, e.g. `waveform a(...); waveform b = a.range(i,j);`: here `range()` returns a view which is copied on a new `waveform`. Anyhow, all this is irrelevant to the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler cannot calculate size of the enclosed class.

You can write `S* s;` though.

Comment: I pretend to be the compiler. 1) I scan S and I find that its size is k. 2) I scan S2 and I find that its size is the one of S. What's the problem? In C++ nested classes have no relationship with their enclosing classes.

Comment: I guess that the first step is not finished (the compiler still doesn't know size of 'S') when it needs to parse 'S2'.

Answer (score 0):

This answer focuses on the **difference** between your two examples, as other answers already explain why the first doesn't work.

In a nutshell, your first example uses `S` within `S` in a way which requires `S` to be complete.

Your second example requires `C` to be complete as soon as the function body is being compiled. Your code is equivalent to

```
struct C {
    struct C1 {
        C makeC();
    };
};

inline C C::C1::makeC() {
    return C();
}
```

That means, the compiler "postpones" the function body automatically. For the function **declaration**, the compiler only needs to know that `C` is a type, but it works if `C` is incomplete, which it is to that point. When the function **definition** is being compiled, the type `C` is now complete.

Comment: Why is it necessary for S to be complete? The compiler could just scan S, determine its size, and then dig into S2 - as S2 does not affect the size of S. Please explain, I can't imagine the reason!

Comment: The standard is designed to make it possible to write `struct S { struct S2 {...}; S2 someInstance; };` As you can see, I added an instance of `S2` in `S`, which makes `sizeof(S)` depend on `sizeof(S::S2)`. I don't see a reason but I guess the committee had a good one to not allow your scenario, which is more or less the opposite. But as you can see in the other answers, there is a workaround; it's somewhat analogous to what the compiler does automatically to function definitions.